# Does an adult male require two kilos of rice per day to reach daily calories requirement?

Tags: rice, calories

I just looked up adult male calorie requirements.  It's 2,500 kcal per day.

There's 1,250 kcal per kilo of basmati rice.

Does that mean I need to eat the calorie equivalent of two kilo bags of rice per DAY??

I actually need to lose a stone and must have done something wrong.  Can anyone help me out to understand how it works?

Comment: Eating only rice would leave you malnourished; energy (calories) is only one part of what your body needs from its diet.

Comment: Hi, I am afraid we don't take questions about nutrition (how much of what should anyone eat). The purely mathematical part of it is OK, but it happens to be a duplicate (the other question is in calories per volume, but you can find a ton of sites which will happily convert rice from weight to volume).

Comment: Agree, no way I'm just eating just rice.

Comment: @rumtscho the other question does not answer my question.  Any ideas where I went wrong.  Surely two kilo bags of rice a day would be crazy?

Comment: @SeanJ we cannot tell you what amount of rice you should, or shouldn't, eat, or what would be "crazy". The other question tells you how to calculate the calories in a given amount of rice.

Comment: @rumtscho yes.b but if I do it I get two kilos of rice. That seems very wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're thinking of dry rice (bags of rice) but that calorie measurement is likely for **cooked** rice. I'm seeing 356 calories per 100g of *raw* (uncooked) rice, which would be nearly triple what you're currently measuring - 130 calories per 100g of cooked rice. Remember that rice absorbs a lot of water when it cooks, so you have to measure the right things. A two kilo bag of rice would have around 7000 calories, not 2,500.

Comment: (Essentially, you're likely making the same error as the person in the duplicate question)